# How do I unzip a sql.xz file using command line in google cloud services?

Tags: google, google-cloud-platform

I have installed gsutil on my machine and started uploading a large DB.  It is in XXXXX.sql.xz format and is 700mb (6gb expanded).

I am hoping that someone can assist me to uncompress it using gsutil commands?  Is this possible.

I apologise for a silly question.  Just learning.  Would be grateful for any decent guidance or tutorials.  I ahve searched and found only unhelpful guides

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) gsutil can be used for a variety of  tasks that include the ones mentioned below. Nevertheless, it is not a compression tool, you need to use standard compression [packages](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-extract-xz-compressed-archive-on-linux).

- Creating and deleting buckets.
- Uploading, downloading, and deleting
  objects.
- Listing buckets and objects.
- Moving, copying, and renaming
  objects.
- Editing object and bucket ACLs.